# "Internal error: couldn't create component peer"

Tags: java, swing, opengl, lwjgl

I keep INTERMITTENTLY having this error when I start my game:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: couldn't create component peer
at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.checkCreation(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.windows.WCanvasPeer.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.windows.WPanelPeer.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.windows.WWindowPeer.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.windows.WFramePeer.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.createFrame(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Frame.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.show(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.show(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Unknown Source)
at Joehot200.TerrainDemo.setUpDisplay(TerrainDemo.java:3569)
at Joehot200.TerrainDemo.startGame(TerrainDemo.java:3640)
at StartScreenExperiments.Test2.resartTDemo(Test2.java:55)
at StartScreenExperiments.Test2.main(Test2.java:41)
```

I am unable to reproduce it, and it appears to simply happen randomly when I start the game - Sometimes, it starts fine, and other times, it has that error.

I'm initiating the display with this code:

```
private void setUpDisplay() {
    //System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", new File("D:/Downloads/mcp/ship/Ship/lib/natives-win").getAbsolutePath());
    try {
        DisplayMode displayMode = null;
        DisplayMode[] modes = Display.getAvailableDisplayModes();

         for (int i = 0; i < modes.length; i++)
         {
             if (modes[i].isFullscreenCapable())
               {
                    displayMode = modes[i];
               }
         }
         if (displayMode == null){
             displayMode = new DisplayMode(100, 100);
         }
         displayMode = Display.getDesktopDisplayMode();
         //Display.setDisplayModeAndFullscreen(new DisplayMode(200, 200));
        //Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(WINDOW_DIMENSIONS[0], WINDOW_DIMENSIONS[1]));
         Display.setDisplayMode(displayMode);
        Display.setResizable(true);
        Display.setTitle("Pirate game");
        //Display.setFullscreen(true);
        try {Thread.sleep(3000);} catch (InterruptedException e1) {}

        frame = new JFrame();

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        try {
            try {Thread.sleep(3000);} catch (InterruptedException e1) {}
            Display.setParent(canvas);

            Display.create();

        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {Thread.sleep(3000);} catch (InterruptedException e1) {}
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.repaint();

    } catch (LWJGLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //cleanUp(true);
    }
}
```

Obviously it is something to do with the JFrame being created (since if I make the display without the JFrame it works fine), however I am currently unable to solve the issue (without ditching JFrames, which I can't do).

I am unsure if the issue has anything to do with LWJGL/OpenGL, so I have tagged it as such anyway.

Comment: Can you try adding thread.sleep for a few seconds just before(and after) gl context creation

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik I presume you mean `try {Thread.sleep(100);} catch (InterruptedException e1) {}` before and after Display.create()?

Comment: Yes but like a sleep(3000) or similar.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik That appears to fix the issue. Obviously I cannot be sure because it is intermittent, however I have tried starting it multiple times and do not come across an error.

Comment: What about adding a separate thread for context in an executor and making it wait until user-interface is ready (with some thread-messaging of your choice)? frame = new JFrame() must be making a new thread I think. Or you can extend JFrame to add your gl context.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that OpenGL's display will only work on the main thread.

Comment: Then you can use event queues maybe?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik Dammit, the problem just happened again. I posted the new code in the original post.

Comment: You should start your UI on the EDT by wrapping it into a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` block. Also, remove those `Thread.sleep`, they will only cause delay, no improvements.

Comment: [See also this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more info.

Comment: I have also seen this error, though it is very rare. All my code uses the EDT, so that is not the cause.

Answer (score 1):

From issue [JDK-8151688](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8151688):

> The most probable cause of the issue: Windows rejects a new window creation because the maximum number of windows is reached.